# Is user group table required when using Yii authManager?

Tags: yii

if I am using Yii's authManager, am I still required to create a user group table? Correct me if I'm wrong, if we're using authManager and RBAC schema, we create roles and assign tasks to it. We then assign roles to a users.

In that case, do we still need a group table and have a FK in the user table that references group table's ID column?

Thank you.

Comment: where did you see this group table? any specific example that you followed?

Comment: Hi, no specific example. I am still learning Yii. I have a tutorial app that I developed with CakePHP previously and I'm using back the same schema to learn Yii.

Comment: ok, so your problem is with roles and its relation to groups?

Comment: well there is no direct relationship, i store my roles in the authItem table, and don't have any group table